# How to edit php.ini file and add extensions to 123-reg site?

Tags: php, sqlsrv

I need to install the sqlsrv driver to a php site hosted on 123-reg. when I load up the website it only says: "Failed to get DB handle: could not find driver"

I can see on phpinfo() that the php.ini file is stored in a folder called etc that I can't seem to find anywhere. The file path is "/etc/php72.ini.d/php.ini"

I also need to copy over the drivers into the extension folder which I can't seem to find either.

How can I find php.ini or create a new one and use that. And how can I install drivers to 123 reg?

I'm using php 7.2.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It sounds like you're on a shared server so you can't do anything like that without the assistance of the system administrator (i.e. your hosting company's support staff). But since you share the server with others, and also provide a specified defined service wihch you pay for and they agree to support, they may not be keen to add additional things to the server or change fundamental configuration. Generally, it's your responsibility to check that the server you're deploying to provides the environment you need _before_ signing up for the service.

Comment: So if "SQL Server support" wasn't specifically listed in the definition of the hosting environment when you were looking at the sales info, it's a question you should have been asking with the sales / technical support people to establish what's provided by default and what it's possible to add. If you want a server where you can do whatever you like, you need a get your own dedicated VPS (virtual private server). But of course this is generally a lot more expensive than getting a slice of a shared one, and you have to do a lot more in terms of maintainence to keep it online and secure.